# No path specified! Can not get relative. vinyl-fs error in gulp task

Tags: javascript, image, gulp, node-modules

I'm suddenly getting this error when trying to build my app using a gulp script that has an "image" task that is failing with this error:

node_modules\vinyl index.js:153

if (!this.path) throw new Error('No path specified! Can not get relative.');

Any idea why this might be happening? I did move these files into a new folder with a different name but I updated my bower.json and package.json files with the new folder name.

```
// Generated on 2016-03-15 using generator-angular 0.15.1
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var openURL = require('open');
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');
var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

var config = {
bowerDir: './bower_components'
}

//app directory structor
var yeoman = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist',
    temp: '.tmp',
    test: 'test'
};

// for sources
var paths = {
    scripts: [yeoman.app + '/scripts/**/*.js'],
    styles: [yeoman.app + '/styles/**/*.scss'],
    test: ['test/spec/**/*.js'],
    testRequire: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.js',
      'bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
    karma: yeoman.test + '/karma.conf.js',
    views: {
        main: yeoman.app + '/index.html',
        bowermain: yeoman.temp + '/index.html',
        files: [yeoman.app + '/views/**/*.html']
    }
};

////////////////////////
// Reusable pipelines //
////////////////////////

var lintScripts = lazypipe()
  .pipe($.jshint) // '.jshintrc'
  .pipe($.jshint.reporter, 'jshint-stylish');

var styles = lazypipe()
  .pipe($.sass, {
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      precision: 10
  })
  .pipe($.autoprefixer, {
      browsers: ['last 2 version']
  })
  .pipe(gulp.dest, yeoman.temp + '/styles');

///////////
// Tasks //
///////////

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles)
      .pipe(styles());
});

gulp.task('lint:scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scripts)
      .pipe(lintScripts());
});

gulp.task('clean:tmp', function (cb) {
    rimraf(yeoman.temp, cb);
});

gulp.task('start:client', ['start:server', 'styles', 'lint:scripts'], function () {
    openURL('http://localhost:9000');
});

gulp.task('start:server', function () {
    $.connect.server({
        root: [yeoman.temp, yeoman.app],
        livereload: true,
        port: 9000,
        middleware: function (connect, opt) {
            return [['/bower_components',
              connect["static"]('./bower_components')]]
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('start:server:test', function () {
    $.connect.server({
        root: [yeoman.test, yeoman.app, yeoman.temp],
        livereload: true,
        port: 9001,
        middleware: function (connect, opt) {
            return [['/bower_components', connect["static"]('./bower_components')]
            ]
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    $.watch(paths.styles)
      .pipe($.plumber())
      .pipe(styles())
      .pipe($.connect.reload())

    $.watch(paths.views.files)
      .pipe($.plumber())
      .pipe($.connect.reload())

    $.watch(paths.scripts)
      .pipe($.plumber())
      .pipe(lintScripts())

    $.watch(paths.test)
      .pipe($.plumber())

    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['bower']);
});

gulp.task('serve', function (cb) {
    runSequence('clean:tmp',
      ['bower'],
      ['lint:scripts'],
      ['start:client'],
      'watch', cb);
});

gulp.task('serve:prod', function () {
    $.connect.server({
        root: [yeoman.dist],
        livereload: {
            port: 810
        },
        port: 800,
        middleware: function (connect, opt) {
            return [['/bower_components', connect["static"]('./bower_components')]
            ]
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('test', ['start:server:test'], function () {
    var testToFiles = paths.testRequire.concat(paths.scripts, paths.test);
    return gulp.src(testToFiles)
      .pipe($.karma({
          configFile: paths.karma,
          action: 'watch'
      }));
});

// inject bower components
gulp.task('bower', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.views.main)
      .pipe(wiredep({
          directory: /*yeoman.app +*/ 'bower_components',
          ignorePath: '..'
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.temp));
});

///////////
// Build //
///////////

gulp.task('clean:dist', function (cb) {
    rimraf(yeoman.dist, cb);
});

gulp.task('client:build', ['bower', 'html', 'styles'], function () {
    var jsFilter = $.filter('**/*.js');
    var cssFilter = $.filter('**/*.css');

    return gulp.src(paths.views.bowermain)
      .pipe($.useref({ searchPath: [yeoman.app, yeoman.temp] }))
      .pipe(jsFilter)
      .pipe($.ngAnnotate())
      .pipe($.uglify())
      .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
      .pipe(cssFilter)
      .pipe($.minifyCss({ cache: true }))
      .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/views/**/*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/views'));
});

gulp.task('copy:data', function () {
    return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/data/**/*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/data'));
});

gulp.task('copy:svg', function () {
    return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/svg/**/*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/svg'));
});



gulp.task('images', function () {
    return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/images/**/*')
      .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
          optimizationLevel: 5,
          progressive: true,
          interlaced: true
      })))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/images'));
});

gulp.task('copy:extras', function () {
    return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/*/.*', { dot: true })
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});

gulp.task('copy:fonts', function () {
    return gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/fonts'));
});

gulp.task('copy:icons', function() {
    return gulp.src('./bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**.*') 
        .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist + '/fonts'));
});


gulp.task('copy:favicon', function () {
    return gulp.src(yeoman.app + '/favicon.ico')
      .pipe(gulp.dest(yeoman.dist));
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean:dist', 'bower'], function () {
    runSequence(['images', 'copy:data', 'copy:extras', 'copy:fonts','copy:icons', 'copy:svg', 'copy:favicon', 'client:build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Comment: Can you provide your gulp script?

Comment: @qxz - I've added my gulp.js

Comment: Is it failing within the `gulp.task('images', function () {`? Can you `console.log(yeoman.app + '/images/**/*')` there? Also, what specifically did you do that caused this error to start happening? (I'm not familiar with gulp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after much hair pulling out and swearing at my monitor I finally figured out what the issue was and hopefully it will help others.

The images all had been initially in a git repository of my prototype project and I copied those using visual studio as add existing to my new project. I'm not sure why but if you open those images in paint.net and save them in the exact same folder with the exact same name and extension they will be marked as changed by git and then if you run your gulp images task you won't get the vinyl error as seen above.

Definitely a head scratcher...

Comment: I think this has something to do with caching as mine worked in the first run.

Answer (score 2):

I disabled caching and it worked. If you are using gulp change this:

```
  gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.cache($.imagemin({
      // some options here
    })))
```

to:

```
  gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
    .pipe($.imagemin({
      // some options here
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this issue on and off with a gulp script I use at work. The answer by haakon.io is what worked for me.

Something with caching causes vinyl.fs trips over certain files in my images folder. Since the site with this script has *a lot* of image resources, I create an images folder on my desktop and grab half of all of the images and drag them out of the folder and run the `gulp images` task. I slowly add resources until I can find the file(s) tripping vinyl. Once I do, resaving that in Photoshop fixes the issue. That workaround has worked best until the scripts can be updated. When you have a lot of images that could be causing this; this is the simplest way I've found to debug.